# Rollover Image effect stop working

Tags: image, rollover

when i put in my social media icons with "Rollover Image", my main navigation rollover image effects stop working. Why is that?

the layout: http://postimg.org/image/n8xfmtodj/

My css:

```
wrapper 
          { width:900; 
           margin:-15px auto 20px auto; 
           background-color:#000;   
           padding:0 40px;
           box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
           background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
           float:none; width:900; height:100%; }

mainNav 
          { width:90%;
           height:90%;
           position:absolute;
           bottom:0px;
           margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
           padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
           text-align:left; }

socialMedia 
              {width:97.5%;
               height:98%;
               position:absolute;
               bottom:0px;
               margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
               padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
               text-align:right }
```

yes i got # before every category in the css docoment just dident get it to work, its my (my first question)